# Sum of hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying to evaluate the following sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^N  {}_2F_1(-n,n-N,1,x) y^n  $$

I notice that according to [wolfram alpha](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/23/02/), 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  {}_2F_1(-n,b,c,x) y^n = \frac{_2F_1(1,b,c,\frac{yx}{x-1})}{1-y}  $$

However, in the question which I want to solve, the b term also varies with n. Any ideas on how to proceed?